# BackgroundTask Clarification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

First, let me say that I have done my research.  I have spent about a day and a half watching videos, reading MSDNs, testing, and experimenting.  I have yet to solve this problem.  Despite all my research, this is going to be fairly broad question, so I apologize for that.  This is probably partially in part due to the newness of Windows Phone 8.1.

My goal is to have an `int` increment once per hour, even when the app is not running.  Clearly, the best way to do this is via a `TimeTrigger` and `BackgroundTask`.  I have created my separate project (`Windows Runtime Component`) called `BackgroundTaskProject` in my solution.  I renamed its class to `BackgroundTaskClass`.  I referenced `BackgroundTaskProject` from my main project.

In `BackgroundTaskClass`, I implemented `IBackgroundTask` and its `Run` method.  **Question 1:  If all I am trying to do is increment a value in my main project, does anything go in this method here?  If so, what?**

I have copy and pasted my `RegisterBackgroundTask` method from MSDN into `BackgroundTaskClass`.

In my main project, I created my `TimeTrigger`.  I registered my `BackgroundTask` via the `static RegisterBackgroundTask` method in `BackgroundTaskClass`.  I made changes so that this `BackgroundTask` is assigned to a variable of type `Task<BackgroundTaskRegistration>` due to the `await`/`async` methods.

**The ultimate question:  Where do I say `myInt++` to have it run once per hour? (`myInt` is in my main project.)**

I can provide specific code or answer questions as requested, but here is some that you may need:

In main project/class:

```
TimeTrigger hourlyTrigger = new TimeTrigger(60, false);
Task<BackgroundTaskRegistration> task = BackgroundTaskProject.BackgroundTaskClass.RegisterBackgroundTask("BackgroundTaskProject.BackgroundTaskClass", "Number Incrementer", hourlyTrigger, null);
```

In `BackgroundTaskClass`:

```
Copy and pasted from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj553413.aspx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very well versed in Windows 8 phone, but I can see you have a basic misconception:
Your myInt goes **nowhere**.

The problem is you are assuming something will be kept always running, but this is not so.

Your main application may be suspended at any time, at this point you should save any data you need to resume the application -> i.e. once suspended your app is gone and it is no longer in memory so there is no myInt to increment.

Your background task fares even worse: it is removed from memory as soon as it finishes execution of the run method -> i.e. if you increment a myInt in your background task then the next time your background task is triggered it will be set to its initial value, because it is a **new** background task.

The correct way to do this is: when your app is started for the first time save the time and intial value of myInt into the app storage. Now whenever you need to figure out the value of myInt simply calculate on the fly from those initial values.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and that thought has crossed my mind, but I was just assuming there was a way to change saved data from the background.  The reason your suggestion will not work, it because I need to use this data to update the live tile (which is present even if the app is suspended).

Comment: http://thesociablegeek.com/windows-8/livetiles/modifying-live-tiles-in-a-background-process/

Comment: Hmmm...seems like a work around, but seems like it should work!  If I take your advice and calculate myInt every 30 minutes from the previously saved value, I should be able to update the tile accurately without updating the actual value!  Great article!

Comment: You can also access the app store from your background task if you need to save state between task triggers.

Comment: Cool.  I will look into that.  You have already been so helpful, but by any chance do you have a source detailing that?  (Or is it in the above article?  I am not finished with that one yet.)

Comment: Sorry no sources, as I said I'm not well versed in Windows 8 Phone, but it seemed you were off-track and no-one more qualified had answered.

Comment: Well i really appreciate it :) I am going to take your advice. I was pretty much stuck, but now I can move forward!